# how to exclude root node in XML for displaying menu?

Tags: asp.net

I want to attach the xml file data to the menu through the XmlDataSource.
I did that but it display from root node. How to do if do not want root node menu. & all the sub menus in same level. eg File, Edit, View etc. Because not to do so then we get unnecessary one extra level for root level menu.

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 4):

Use the XmlDataSource.XPath property to specify the entry point to the data you want to show for example

```
XmlDataSource.XPath = "xml/submenus";
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the XPath to point to the correct tags in the xml file.

ASPX:
`XPATH="ROOT/TARGET"`

XML:

```
<ROOT>
  <TARGET TEXT="STARTS HERE">
    <DATA TEXT="OTHER DATA HERE" />
  </TARGET>
</ROOT>
```